# Seg fault when trying to compute Arithmetic Operation Time in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, clock, time.h

I am writing a program that multiplies two Matrice's and the third Matrix prints the results. Along with that I want to compute the arithmetic operation time that I specified in my code below, however I keep getting a segmentation fault and I believe I am using the time.h/clock() library function correctly. Ive provided a snippet of the section giving me problems.

```
    /**  Third Matrix  **/ 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            arr3[i][x] = 0;
            for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
                arr3[i][x] = arr3[i][x] + arr1[i][y] * arr2[y][x];
        }
    }

    arithmeticBegin = clock(); //begins the clock for arithmetic time

    //the following line is what was causing the seg fault
    arr3[i][x] = arr3[i][x] + arr1[i][y] * arr2[y][x];

    arithmetic_endTime = clock(); //stops the clock for the end of arithmetic time
    /**  The following computers total arithmetic Time **/
    arithmeticTime += (double)(arithmetic_endTime - arithmeticBegin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without a [mcve].

Comment: @FredLarson I have added the complete code.

Comment: Where in the program does the segmentation fault occur? Use gdb to find out.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I have commented which line is causing the segmenttion fault.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  //the following line is what was causing the seg fault
>   arr3[i][x] = arr3[i][x] + arr1[i][y] * arr2[y][x];
> ```

That's because you are accessing the arrays using out of bounds indices for all the arrays.

Remove that line. It does not seem to be doing anything useful.

---

Couple more observations.

1. Your computations are likely causing integer overflow since `rand()` can return anything between `[0 - RAND_MAX]`. You may want to use a smaller number for the elements of your matrix, such as `rand() % 100000`.
2. The `printf` call creates output without any whitespace between elements. You may want to to add a space between the elements.

   ```
    printf ("%4d ", arr3[i][x]);
   ```

Comment: Just to be clear, that line is fine in the loop, but when the loop ends `i` and `x` are outside the bounds.

Comment: That is there because it is what I am trying to find the computation time of.

Comment: @Chris You should be getting the computation time of the loop, that's where all the work is.